# Jquery, Flot: Can't show right yaxis label and align axis at the same time

Tags: jquery, flot

this is my flot jquery code:

```
$.plot("#area-graph-hi", [{
    data: [[0, -1.0], [1, 0.17], [2, 0.0], [3, 1.0], [4, 0.67], [5, -1.33], [6, -2.0], [7, 1.67], [8, 0.0], [9, 1.67], [10, 1.67]],
    yaxis: 1,
    color: "#3261ab",
    label: "Performance of the area",
    bars: { show: true, barWidth: 0.5, align: "center" }
},{
    data: [[0, 0], [1, 1.0], [2, 1.0], [3, 2.0], [4, 1.0], [5, 1.0], [6, 3.0], [7, 3.0], [8, 0.0], [9, 2.0], [10, 0.0]],
    yaxis: 2,
    color: "#1e8052",
    label: "Combined flooding event severity scenarios",
    bars: { show: true, barWidth: 0.5, align: "center" }
}
],{
    grid: {
        hoverable: false,
        clickable: false
    },
    xaxis:{
        ticks: [[0,0], [1, "1"], [2, "2"], [3, "3"], [4, "4"], [5, "5"], [6, "6"], [7, "7"], [8, "8"], [9, "9"], [10, "10"]]
    },
    yaxis: {
        tickDecimals: 0,
    },
    axisLabels: {
        show: true
    },
    xaxes: [{
        axisLabel: 'Year of simulation',
        axisLabelPadding: 30
    }],
    yaxes: [{
        position: 'right',
        axisLabel: 'Performance of the area'
    },{
        position: 'left',
        alignTicksWithAxis: 1,
        axisLabelPadding: 20,
        axisLabel: 'Combined flooding event severity scenarios'
    }]
});
```

The problem is that I cannot align the two x-axis. If I do, align the two x-axis together, I can't show the label on the right axis. What am I doing wrong?

(here is a pic of the current result: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2423935/flot.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you create pictures of what you get with and without aligning and a third of what you what to achieve (by using Paint or similar)?

Comment: If you load the picture I have attached (using the public link above) you will see that there are two y-axis that are not aligned. I want those y-axis to be aligned. For some reason, when I manage to do that (align the two y-axis), the right label does not show on the graph.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the ticks for both y axis so that both have the same number of ticks?

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. But how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: Just as you do it for the x axis.